# Generate Byte Array from Stream

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, arrays, filestream

I am trying to generate byte array from a stream of ".rtf" file.
The code is as follows:

```
Public Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Try
        Dim result As System.Nullable(Of Boolean) = textDialog.ShowDialog()

        If result = True Then
            Dim fileStream As Stream = textDialog.OpenFile()

            GetStreamAsByteArray(fileStream)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

Private Function GetStreamAsByteArray(ByVal stream As System.IO.Stream) As Byte()

    Dim streamLength As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length)

    Dim fileData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLength) {}

    ' Read the file into a byte array
    stream.Read(fileData, 0, streamLength)
    stream.Flush()
    stream.Close()

    Return fileData

End Function
```

The above code generates stream length for the file opened however the byte array returned only have 0's in the array.
How can i generate correct byte array?

Answer (score 1):

You function does not returns the byte array to any object. This example works for me:

```
 Dim bytes = GetStreamAsByteArray(textDialog.File.OpenRead)
 MessageBox.Show(bytes.Length.ToString)
```

Comment: textDialog.File.OpenRead is not available

Comment: I ran a test in Silverlight, what version are you using?